# wordpress admin panel, how to prevent users from deleting categories?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, admin, panel

I'm trying to remove, hide or disable "Delete" button out of category editing section
Code i've tried. No luck. Any ideas?

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_category_buttons');
function hide_category_buttons() {
  echo '<style>
    .taxonomy-category tr:hover .row-actions {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>';
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to remove, hide or disable "Delete" button out of category
> editing section Code i've tried. No luck. Any ideas?

The following code should do what you want:

- "Delete" button, **hidden** and **blocked** on post taxonomy `category` AND it's edit page.
- "Delete" button, **hidden** and **blocked** on post taxonomy `tags` AND it's edit page.

I've also added a conditional statement regarding the user capability. If a user can edit a post, he won't be concerned by the our restriction.

*You can learn more about the `current_user_can()` function @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/*

Everything as been tested on my end and it's working.

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'admin_restriction' );
function admin_restriction() {
  if ( is_admin() && strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category' ) || strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], 'term.php?taxonomy=category' ) || strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag' ) || strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], 'term.php?taxonomy=post_tag' ) ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) { //Define use capability here
      add_action( 'admin_head', 'admin_scripts' );
      function admin_scripts() {
        echo "<style type='text/css'>
        .delete {
          display: none;
          visibility: hidden; }
        </style>";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
          $( '.delete-tag' ).click( false ); } );
        </script>";
      };
    };
  };
}; ?>
```